# Why does a code block that contains only comments seem to change key bindings?

Tags: org-mode, key-bindings, org-babel

This is very odd.

I have my Emacs config in code blocks in an `org-mode` file that is called from my init file using `(org-babel-load-file "~/.emacs.d/emacs-config.org")`.

I've tried to assign some new key-bindings:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'browse-url-emacs) ; plain text
  (global-set-key (kbd "C-c j") 'browse-url) ; default browser
#+end_src
```

For a reason that I don't understand, this breaks other key bindings. After restarting emacs, for example, `C-x f` is  bound to the default `set-fill-column` instead of `recentf-ido-find-file`, to which I had it reassigned.

This is confusing, because there is no overlap between the key-bindings. But what's really weird is that the problem persists even when I comment out the new key-bindings in the code block:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle yes
; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'browse-url-emacs) ; plain text
; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c j") 'browse-url) ; default browser
#+end_src
```

The problem goes away if I instruct `org-babel` to ignore the code block (using the `:tangle no` property:

```
#+begin_src emacs-lisp :tangle no
; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c h") 'browse-url-emacs) ; plain text
; (global-set-key (kbd "C-c j") 'browse-url) ; default browser
#+end_src
```

Why do commands that are commented out seem to affect my config? (And in such a weird way?)

And why do these new key bindings mess up existing ones?

Comment: I think the file is tangled into `~/.emacs.d/emacs-config.el`  so you should take a look at this file and see what it contains in the various cases. That will probably help you understand what's going on. If you still have problems, you might want to add that file to your question if it's short enough - or better yet, you might be able to reproduce the problem with a much smaller `emacs-config.org` file and *then* post the resulting `.el` file in your question.

Comment: Thanks, will do. @Drew thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 1):

For an unknown reason, `org-babel` truncated the tangled file (`emacs-config.el`) above the problematic code snippet. All settings above the snippet were therefore lost. As NickD said in a comment, it is crucial to examine the tangled file for troubleshooting.

The full file was tangled once I removed (not changed) the `:tangle yes` property from the code snippet. I don't know why having the property caused the preceding (but not the subsequent) code blocks not to be tangled. (Perhaps either each block or no block must have the property set, but this seems like unexpected behavior, not like a feature.)